# Stop function inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
var test = setTimeout(function () {
    while (true) {
        console.log('Test');
    }
}, 5);

clearTimeout(test);
```

I have this piece of code that represents my problem, will `clearTimeout(test)` stop while loop?

Comment: Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout might give you some thoughts? Somehow I've a feeling, that you'd need `setInterval` instead.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Just copy and paste the code into the console and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will not run before timeout is over or if you clear the timeout.

```
var t = setInterval(myFunction,5000)
 clearInterval(t)
 function myFunction() {
 //your content
} //The above function will not run.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `clear the timeout` of a function this will make your function not to be called after the time setted.

This `clearTimeout(variable)` function doesn't stop the execution of the method when you are looping inside a setTimeout.

you can try doing something like this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    console.log('Test');
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: And do I have a way to stop the execution of a method?

Comment: can you update the question with some code? @AntónioGarcez

Comment: I change question, I hope that, now, you can understand my problem

Comment: *"This `clearTimeout(variable)` function doesn't stop the execution of the method."* Are you sure? It should be .

Comment: thanks, but your answer don't solve my problem, I need a command that abort the execution of a function...and I can't use vars

Comment: @FelixKling you are right this was part of the previous answer, wrong edited. my bad.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't test code that I have put in question. I put this code to show an example of my real problem. But `clearTimeout` should stop execution in my example?

Comment: @AntónioGarcez: Yes.

Comment: @FelixKling I tested and don't stop the execution of loop :'(

Comment: @AntónioGarcez: Then maybe we misunderstood each other. It won't stop the loop if it is already running. But your exact example will prevent the scheduled function from every being executed.

Comment: @FelixKling: The `clearTimeout` isn't execute right after declaration of var. My question was if `clearTimeout` can stop execution of loop?

Comment: @AntónioGarcez: No. `clearTimeout` is for "unscheduling" a function that is supposed to be executed in the future. If your `while` loop runs, the obviously the function was already executed, so it cannot be "unscheduled". Besides, during the execution of the `while` loop, no other code can be executed. JavaScript is single threaded.